# want to call webservice through outlook email html body

Tags: javascript, blackberry, outlook, outlook-addin

I want to either call a web service using AJAX/JQuery or send an SMTP mail when the user clicks on some image / button in blackberry device.

I tried the below approaches

1) Tried to create custom outlook form and publish it on OFL but client does not want this.
2) So created HTML based template to send emails using MAPI but inline JavaScript / jquery scripts does not work may be because security reason (as many blogs / post say the same).

Workaround I found is

1)Open an HTML page as popup and call webservice using AJAX/JQuery and then close the window automatically or OK button click.
NOTE : For this we have to host HTML page which is again an overhead.

Also client do not want any plugin to be installed anywhere on their system or devices

Comment: Well, seems really like a security restriction. Email in Blackberry is quite restrictive... Could you detail what you want to achieve with the image / button? What kind of business goal do you have? Maybe there's a different approach. Why not just have some website where the user logs in once and then has a cookie. Each time he opens it, it will show the options he can click... I don't see why this would be a big overhead...

Comment: @Martin : Many thanks for the response , It is actually a approve / reject workflow , the approver will receive an email on his / her blackberry device through which he has to send the response. He may not want to click on reply button as their will be many links inside the HTML body. Hosting a website wont be difficult as you said but that I am keeping as last resort.

Comment: OK, I am not an expert with blackberry mail implementations, maybe someone who has better experience with this can answer your question. It would be great if you could append the minimum Blackberry version your sw is targeting. As a last resource, you would have to implement the html page approach, however, unless you will be having a really high volume, overhead shouldn't be an issue, I would rather care about the usability inconvinience that such an implementation might cause.